# MSAL Library Redirect Uri not coming in Android App

Tags: android, azure, azure-ad-msal

**What will be the hyperlink value in html for Android(So that Android can catch) & in which override method of msal the hyperlink/intent will come?**

We have implemented MSAL v4.5.0 in our Android app. In our Manifest we have this below configuration added.

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="<pkg_name>"
                android:path="/<signature_hash>"
                android:scheme="msauth" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

auth_config.json

```
{
  "client_id": "client_id",
  "redirect_uri": "msauth://<pkg_name>/<Signature_hash>",
  "account_mode": "MULTIPLE",
  "broker_redirect_uri_registered": false,
  "authorization_user_agent": "WEBVIEW",
  "web_view_zoom_controls_enabled": false,
  "web_view_zoom_enabled": false,
  "logging": {
    "pii_enabled": true,
    "log_level": "VERBOSE",
    "logcat_enabled": true
  },
  "authorities": [
    {
      "type": "B2C",
      "authority_url": "<url>",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "B2C",
      "authority_url": "<url>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now when we are opening our policy page in that page we have an anchor tag like this below.

`<a href="https://our_domain/signup">Signup Here</a>`

Now by clicking that link, it is trying to open another page within that browser. What we want is by clicking on that hyperlinking it should close the microsoft browser and give us the url (https://our_domain/signup) as an intent.

Now iOS is following the same approach in html, for iOS herf is

`<a href="msauth.<pkg_name>://?signup">Signup Here</a>`

They are able to catch ***msauth.<pkg_name>://?signup*** the entire part in there Application class.

We have also gone through this docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#redirect-uri-for-public-client-apps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-android-single-sign-on